# C# Database call inside parallel loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, parallel-processing

I've come across a code where I've seen some database call inside Parallel Loop. so, the question comes to my mind is that database call is thread-safe because Parallel loop executes in multiple threads.

Here is the small piece of code for your review:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
{
    //this function update the user status by connecting with database
    _IUserRepository.UpdateUserStatus(item.UserId, item.status);
});
```

Is each thread of parallel loop, wait for updation of user status?

What will happen, if we're having the record in the list as below:

```
UserId, Status
1,0
1,1
1,0
1,1
```

- What will be the final status of the user having id=1?
- Are there any chances of deadlock or race condition here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to talk about the thread safety of unknown code. *Performance* though will probably suffer a lot, as multiple connections compete of the same resources. If you have performance issues, the problem is the code itself and won't improve with parallelization.

Comment: For example, if all you execute is a single row update, almost 80% of the time spent for each update is network traffic. You can improve performance almost 80 times if you *batch* 100 updates together, or pass the values as a table-valued parameter. Better yet, push the changes using SqlBulkCopy to a staging table and execute a single UPDATE on the server. SqlBulkCopy uses minimal logging and locking - instead of logging every row, it logs entire pages. With a staging table, you won't have any locking issues either.

Comment: More mundane issues - if `UserID` isnt' the first column of an index, every UPDATE will result in a full table scan. Index it and performance will increase by orders of magnitude

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for details comments. That's very helpful for me.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "sql-server" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot tell if this code is "thread-safe" because it depends on if `_IUserRepository.UpdateUserStatus` is thread-safe and we don't have source code for it. Assuming it's thread safe, final status of user in your case is still indetermindate: whatever `UPDATE` statement hit database last will win and overwrite all previous changes for given user. As for deadlock - I don't see anything that can deadlock here. That said - having multiple updates for the same user with different status in such list already does not make much sense. Only one entry for any given user should be in such a list (so it should be a `Dictionary` keyed by user id).

Answer (score 0):

> Is each thread of parallel loop, wait for updation of user status?

I guess that the answer is depends. Depends on your data base Transaction Level. The higher the level, the more chances that the threads will have to wait for each other when updating the same record in the DB. If the list is a list of different users, I recon that it should not be the case.

> What will be the final status of the user having id=1?

That can't be predicted for sure. For every run you can end up with different answer. But I don't think that this code was written for this scenario, but rather for the case when you have a list with different users. Otherwise the code does not makes sense.

> Are there any chances of deadlock or race condition here?

Deadlocks no, race condition yes, only if you consider the example you just gave above. But again, as mentioned, I think that this code applies for a list with different users.